# The question About generate office 's Word file on Android project

Tags: android

use iText-2.1.5.jar  and iText-rtf-2.1.4.jar,I can successfully generate office's Word file on java project.On Android project,can be compiled by eclipse,but run error on the Android emulator.I consider that whether the iText-2.1.5.jar and iText-rtf-2.1.4.jar are be complied into apk? anyone can help me ?

Thanks in advance

the error：
06-12 11:33:50.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(804): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lowagie.text.Document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JAR files should be in the `libs/` directory of your project, plus added to your build path in Eclipse.

Comment: hello,I new a Folder named as libs in my project and set "Use as Source Folder",then paste my JAR files into it. but I build project error.                                                              [2011-06-13 11:35:48 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: null
[2011-06-13 11:35:48 - HelloAndroid] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: null

Comment: @ibraver: I do not know what "Use as Source Folder" is, but that does not sound right. Your JAR files should be in the `libs/` directory of your project, plus added to your **build path** in Eclipse.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for help me.I'm a beginner of Android.I'm sorry to spend your time.whether "plus added to your build path in Eclipse" means that select the properties of Android project named as  properties==>java Build Path ==>Source==>Add Folder ,like this to do or not. do you teach me specific ? Thanks

Comment: @ibraver: Use Build Path > Configure Build Path. Then, in the Build Path dialog, choose the Libraries tab. Then, click the "Add JARs..." button. Then, find the JAR in your `libs/` directory.

Comment: Excuse me.I do like that but build project error             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /HelloAndroid
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.newResource(Workspace.java:1628)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.getFolder(Container.java:137)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.PreCompilerBuilder.buildAidlCompilationList(Unknown Source)

Comment: @ibraver: All I can tell you is that this recipe works for normal Android Eclipse projects.

Comment: ok,Although not solve this problem,But Thanks for your help.then,I will try it again.